# Xamarin custom font shows in preview but not in build

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, font-awesome

I am struggling a bit here. I am trying to get FontAwesome to work in my iOS application, and I think I am really close (but no cigar).

When looking at my project in visual studios preview window (iOS) everything looks like it should and i can see the fa icons, but when building to phone or simulator I get squares with "?" inside :-/

Here is how I try to accomplish this:

```
var thisBtn = new Button()
{
    HeightRequest = 60,
    WidthRequest = 60,
    Text = "\uf007",
    FontSize = 60,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
    Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0),
    TextColor = Color.FromHex("#204353")
};

thisBtn.FontFamily = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS ? "FontAwesome5ProLight" : null;
```

I have included the fonts in my info.plist like this:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
    <string>fa-brands-400.ttf</string>
    <string>fa-light-300.ttf</string>
    <string>fa-solid-900.ttf</string>
    <string>fa-regular-400.ttf</string>
</array>
```

I am really confused and i am hoping for help :-)

Comment: Can you the path off fontaswesome.tff it's root or on correct directory.Some dictionary path not acceptable in mobile or simulators.please check it.

Comment: Why do you use "FontAwesome5ProLight" instead of "FontAwesome"?

Comment: @AnupPatil - I had the font inside "Resources -> Fonts". I moved them out of the "Fonts" folder and now it works :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your path location of fontaswesome.tff,Also check it's root or on correct directory.
Some dictionary path not acceptable in mobile or simulators.please check it.